# Geth with clique block sealing without unlock account

Tags: geth

Hello I have a local blockchain, Geth client, 2 nodes and clique proof of authority algorithm.

I start geth with this command:

```
geth --datadir node2/ --syncmode 'full' --port 30312 
     --rpc --rpcport 8546 --rpccorsdomain "*" 
     --ipcpath geth.ipc --rpcapi 'personal,db,eth,net,web3,txpool,miner' 
     --bootnodes 'enode://702efed8e606...ad041b4371a91989@127.0.0.1:30310' 
     --networkid 2456 --gasprice '1' --mine 
     --unlock '0x46004DEAfddb60d11cA04501df8C52aE4679Be8f' --password password.txt
```

but because of unlock now everyone can transfer ether from this account to some other account

like so:

```
const Web3 = require("web3");    
var web3Client = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8546"));
await web3Client.eth.sendTransaction({
  from: "0x46004DEAfddb60d11cA04501df8C52aE4679Be8f", 
  to: "0xE77e5634A46153e1cfCa02350cf212BdbC18fbC6", 
  value: 23
});
```

but if I remove --unlock from geth command I can no longer seal blocks

```
WARN [06-01|14:44:52] Block sealing failed    err="authentication needed: password or unlock"
```

is it possible to seal blocks in some other way so I won't have to unlock the account anymore?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, geth needs access to the private key to sign transactions, so you have to have it unlocked, otherwise it can't sign.

What you can do, is have this node signing, and get rid of
--ipcpath geth.ipc --rpcapi 'personal,db,eth,net,web3,txpool,miner'
instead, give the rpc to another node without an unlocked account.

Use this other node for all your interactions, and allow the first one to sign.

Cheers;
Evan

Comment: This worked for me, it's worth to mention that I configured the member node to always connects to the signing node via static-nodes.json https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Connecting-to-the-network#static-nodes.